# Using custom HTML helpers in orchard CMS driver's editor template

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm try to create a new content part with custom HTML helper package,
for this i have to bind list of items as value for this control in template page.

My requirement is to render Grid control in custom content part's display template page and get details on editor template page.

In editor template how to get list of items and how to bind this for display template page.

Please share details about this

Thanks,

Comment: What grid control is this? What did you try, and how did it not work? Where does the list of items come from?

Comment: Grid -  this is grid control to display list of items in content parts display view page. In edit view page  i cant store multiple items in model record. I need to know how to create form for save multiple items in edit view page of content part. And then i want to bind this list of items from model record to grid control in display view page of content part. Is this possible?

Comment: It's probably possible, but you're not giving enough details to tell if and how, and you also didn't answer my question.